# youtube downloadable links in php

Tags: php, youtube

I am unable to get the youtube downloadable links.
I am using the below line of code to get the url links.

```
$data =file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$id);
```

but for some video ids it is working and for some of them it is not working.
Is there any new technique to get downloadable links the video from youtube url.

The technique I used is to get the source code->find `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map` till  -> then decoding the url ->then seperateing the downloadable links from that.

For Example i am trying to download the below youtube url:-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKRtwNMRbb4

Then i am below geting this link as download link:-

https://r3---sn-aigs6n7y.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=o-ALWyuhYomxf55RTD7AHI7Y8E26JM6SAl0ipmPOzZ1ssZ&mn=sn-aigs6n7y&mm=31&pl=24&dur=1907.124&lmt=1471163173533220&ip=31.170.164.31&ms=au&ei=qMaaWabDKsvMW8n8mPAC&mv=u&mt=1503315355&expire=1503337224&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&key=yt6&beids=%5B9466593%5D&ipbits=0&mime=video%2Fmp4&itag=22&source=youtube&ratebypass=yes?title=Gangster%20|%20%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F%E0%A4%B0%20|%20%E0%A4%87%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%20%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80%20|%20All%20Songs%20|%20Emraan%20Hashmi%20|%20Kangna%20Ranaut%20|%20Audio%20Jukebox

Comment: Define "not working" - are you getting an error? Please provide more detail.

Comment: the link which i am getting is not a valid one to download the video.